# find not overlapping ranges

Tags: matlab, compare, intervals

I have 2 vectors

```
Upper_bound =   [421.1706;418.7937;425.9144;431.7096];
Lower_bound =   [376.0487;395.4193;402.7083;419.0457];
```

Representing the 95% confidence intervals of 4 measurements (`A,B,C,D`).
How can I calculate in an automatic way whether there are significant differences between measures (i.e. 95% confidence intervals do not overlap).

my preferred output would be:

```
sign_diff = [0 0 0 0; 
             0 0 0 1; 
             0 0 0 0; 
             0 1 0 0];
```

Indicating that A does not differ from A,B,C,D.

B does not differ from A,B,C but it differs from D.

etc.

Thanks

Comment: sounds like a inverse problem (ax=b)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun) to do the computation

```
sign_diff = bsxfun( @ge, Lower_bound, Upper_bound' ) |...
            bsxfun( @le, Upper_bound, Lower_bound' )
```

Results with:

```
sign_diff =
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0
```

Comment: @gabboshow I accidentally mixed the lower and upper bounds. please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Taking [Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai):

```
sign_diff = ~(bsxfun( @le, Lower_bound, Upper_bound' ) &...
             bsxfun( @ge, Upper_bound, Lower_bound' ))
```

I can't comment yet, so I post it as answer.